# Sitecore Weblog module pagination

Tags: pagination, sitecore

I'm currently working on a sitecore website which uses the Weblog module. I have never used this and so far everything is working except for the pagination when showing the list of all the posts.

If looked around on the internet and found the following documentation:
http://www.sundance.org/temp/eedoc/modules/weblog/pagination_page.html

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="news" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="1" paginate="bottom"}

<h2>{title}</h2>

{summary}

{body}

{paginate}
<p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}

{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

If been staring on this for a long time but unfortunatly if have no clue how or where to implement this. Can anyone help me on this or knows a different approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you look to different WeBlog module. What are you showing us is not same module with [WeBlog](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/WeBlog.aspx) for Sitecore. You are looking [ExpressionEngine WeBlog module](http://ee1docs.com/modules/weblog/index.html).

Comment: Okay that's what I was thinking but wasn't sure.
Do you know a way to do it with the weblog module cause i can't seem to find a lot of documentation